# image view of an image in grid view

Tags: android

I am  making an android application in which I have to rotate an image in grid view . I have written the following code:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

            .............

     int position = parent.pointToPosition(x, y);
    switch(me.getAction())
    {


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        //int z = fPosition(x,y);
        sr = position;
        doRotation(v,position);

        //startAnimation(v);
        //Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "down "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        //popUp.dismiss();
        ds = position;
        images.cPositions(sr,ds);
        images.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //int z1 = fPosition(x,y);
    //Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "up " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        //Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}


 void doRotation(View v, int position) {

    final ImageView im;
    final RotateAnimation rAnim;
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mlinear);

    rAnim = new RotateAnimation(0f,360, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rAnim.setStartOffset(0);
    rAnim.setDuration(2000);
    rAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    rAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    v.startAnimation(rAnim);
}
```

I am on android 2.2(8 level) what its doing is its rotating whole grid view I want to rotate on of the image . Just want to know how to get the image view of an image in grid view..

Answer (score 0):

I think to `GridView` you are setting `onTouchListener`. That is why its rotating whole view. Try to set Listener for views in GridView. Its better to implement `setOnItemClickListener` so that you can easily get the item you clicked.

Comment: actually i had implemented drag and drop by OnTouchListener (i have to use it).....so there is any other way.....how could i get cell id of the cell in grid view....